# Microchip proximity detection system

Tags: proximity-sensor

Is there any type of proximity system that detects a microchip or similar?  I am looking at an "mobile" proximity detection system that I could specifically detect an implanted or imbedded microchip or something that it would be designed to only detect that object.  It would also be very beneficial to be microchip size.  This would be for an industrial application.  Thank you in advance.
           JL

Comment: You'll find that the problem is that "or similar" will end up casting a very wide net.

Comment: Are you looking for active chips only, or inactive/unpowered ones as well? Do you need to directly detect the silicon chip, or is it OK to detect it indirectly, through, say, the properties of its lead frame or other packaging? Silicon chips are basically indistinguishable from sand.

Comment: Is whatever you want to do in any way different from what's already done on an industrial scale with RFID tags? The tag is tiny, detection systems can be quite long range, and they are widely available for everything from "injectables for pet identification" to things embedded in products from clothing to computers to cars for inventory and/or counterfeiting control. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification

Comment: Talk to your local vet (veterinary doctor, not ex-army!). Just tell him it's for your cat...

Answer (score 1):

My cats have these fitted: -

[image]

They are uniquely coded so no two cats (or dogs or rabbits) have the same number.

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchip_implant_%28animal%29) the wiki link.

Answer (score 0):

You need what is refereed to as "a Ferromagnetic Detection System" - such systems are used in hospitals during MRI screening.